# Unexpected order of output UsIng Async-Await in JavaScript, Need Explanations

Tags: javascript, ajax, asynchronous, async-await, promise

For the following code:-

```js
let p1 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log("one");
    resolve("data1");
  }, 8000)
})
let p2 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log("two");
    resolve("data2");
  }, 5000)
})

let func1 = async() => {

  await p1;
  console.log("middle");
  await p2;

}

func1();
```

In my understanding of async-await, the output of the above code should be:

---

```
    one  
    middle  
    two
```

---

and the total runtime I expect is 13 seconds

The reason I think this is because with await we can execute the promises in order and the control should move to the next line (i.e console.log("middle")) only after the resolve() of first promise(p1) is invoked. So according to me the code would be run in a way that it encounters the line "await p1;" and then it waits 8 seconds to get resolved and then move to the next line and so on.

But the output I am getting in the console is:

---

```
    two
    one
    middle
```

---

and the total runtime is around 8 seconds and not the expected 13 seconds.

can someone explain what i am getting wrong here?

Comment: Promises start resolving as soon as they're created. You need to turn p1 and p2 into functions that return the promises. Fixed: https://jsfiddle.net/fqg2uyad/

Answer (score 2):

The timer callbacks aren't in anyway held up or delayed by the fact you're awaiting a completely separate promise.

Your confusion might be the common one of thinking promises *do* something. :-) They don't. The function you pass to `new Promise` (the *promise executor* function) **synchronously** and **immediately** when you call `new Promise`, not later when you *use* the promise. Its purpose is to *start* the asynchronous process that the promise will observe/report the completion of. So your `setTimeout` calls are executed right away, one right after the other. Since you're doing the `"one"` and `"two"` `console.log`s in the `setTimeout` callback, you see `"two"` after five seconds and `"one"` three seconds later (after eight seconds).

You don't see `"middle"` until the second promise is fulfilled because (as I think you understand), your `await` makes the code in that `async` function wait for the first promise to be settled before continuing. But that `await` doesn't have any effect on when the timer callback runs.

Answer (score 0):

Promises are run as soon as they are instantiated. So in your example both `p1` and `p2` execute as soon as you create the promise. They both set a specific timeout that resolves the promise by writing to the console and calling `resolve`.

Then, you wait for `p1` to resolve. It takes 8 seconds, as expected from the timeout. But before that happens, the timeout for `p2` ends, so the "inner" part of the promise is called, writing `two` to the console and resolving `p2`.

Once the 8 seconds elapse, `p1` writes `one` to the log and resolves. Then your code continues executing, writing `middle`. The final `await` does nothing, as `p2` has already resolved when it is invoked.

For the code to work as you want, you should create `p2` after the `await p1` line, or, even better, chain `p1` and `p2` using `.then()`, so that `p2` starts running once `p1` has resolved.

Comment: so what you are essentially saying is that when i write:-

`let p1 = new Promise(.......)`

It instantaneously starts executing statements in the callback passed to the new Promise 
and writing `await p1;`after it will just make sure that before moving to the next line(i.e lines after  "await p1") that p1 promise is not in the pending state?

Comment: Yes, that's a good way to look at it. @T.J.'s reply has a good explanation of why this happens. Also - besides waiting, `await` returns the resolve value of the promise, so if you change `await p2` to `console.log(await p2)` you will see `data2` in the log in the place you expect it to appear.